# PythonでMicrosoftWordの.doc形式のファイルからテキストを抽出する方法

Tags: python, python3, windows, ms-word

お世話になります。

PythonでWord文章の表部分を取り出して、CSVで保存するツールを作ろうとしています。
そこで、その前段階として、Wordから文章を取得して、テキストファイルに変換しようとしています。

とりあえず、python-docxライブラリでできそうなことはわかったのですが、.docxのファイルは読み込めますが、.doc形式のファイルが読み込めずに困っています。
また、COMを使う方法もあるようですが、Wordがインストールされていないと利用できないと思われるため、除外しています。
何か良い方法はないでしょうか。

なお、対象OSはWindowsとし、MacOSやLinuxは除外します。
また、Pythonのバージョンは3.7系を利用します。

それから、できれば外部の実行ファイル（.exeファイル）を呼び出す方法ではなく、Python単体で実装することができれば助かります。

以上、何かアドバイスを頂けると幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: python-docxは.docには非対応と公式ドキュメントに書いてありますね。https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html どうしてもdocxではなくdocを読む必要があるのであればIronPythonとか使うといいかもしれません。

Comment: @shirakia IronPythonは.NET Framework上で動作するだけであり、.docを読み込めるかどうかとは無関係に思うのですが、何か利点があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 条件は全然満たしていないのですが、こういう記事があります。[Best way to extract text from a Word doc without using COM/automation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42482/9014308) さらに日本語に対応しているかは不明ですが。

Comment: .NETが使えるとMS-Wordが読みやすい、というか実績がたくさんあります。ironpython ms word docとかでググると良いと思います。

Comment: それとは別にtextractというのを発見しました。これが良いかも？

Comment: ありがとうございます。とりあえず、textractを試してみようと思い、pipでインストールしてみようとしましたが、インストール段階でエラーが表示され、そこから進めずにいます。また、IronPythonも検討してみますが、環境構築をしないといけないので、しばらく時間がかかりそうです。また何か進展したら報告させていただきます。

Comment: @shirakia 「ironpython ms word doc」でググってみましたが最初の9件は質問で除外されているCOMを使う方法でした。10件目は`doc`でなく`docx`を解析するものでなおかつ`ironpython`を含んでいませんでした。やはりIronPythonを使うのは的外れに思います。

Comment: お世話になります。私もIronPythonの環境を構築する前にざっと検索してみましたが、見つけられませんでした。発想を変えて、docをdocxに変換してから読み込むということも考えましたが、これも難しいようでした。ということで、今回はとりあえずdocxだけということにしたいと思います。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

お世話になります。

今回の条件で、DOCファイルをテキストに変換するのは難しそうなので、あきらめることにしました。
　ありがとうございました。